# What's the proper way to access parameters from within Ember.Route. setupController?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

`Ember.Route.model` has access to the `params` variable, but `Ember.Route.setupController` does not. This is troublesome for me, because my path has multiple dynamic segments, and I need to use all of them in my template.

Specifically, my path looks like this: `/project/:project_id/task/:task_id`. Note that a task can belong to many projects, not just one. Therefore we can't tell what project we're looking at just be looking at the task itself: we have to use the project ID found in the URL. Here's how I'm doing it currently:

```
App.TaskRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  // This works just fine:
  serialize: function(model) {
    return {
      task_id: model.get('id'),
      project_id: this.modelFor('project').get('id')
    };
  },

  model: function(params) {
    this.set('parentProjectId', params.project_id);

    return App.Task.find(params.task_id);
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    var parentProject = this.modelFor('project') ?
                        this.modelFor('project') :
                        App.Project.find(this.get('parentProjectId'));
    controller.set('parentProject', parentProject);

    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

Maybe I'm being paranoid, this just feels hacky. If the route was meant to have access to the parameters, then it would already have a `params` property attached to it. Is there a better way?

EDIT: I made some update to the code above. Also, my routes look like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('project', { path: '/project/:project_id' });
  this.resource('task', { path: 'project/:project_id/task/:task_id' });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have no access to these params in the setupController hook. **The model hook has access to a params object, because it is just called, when your app is entered via URL.**

Your code looks quite fine, it you really know, that you want to do it this way. What does feel hacky to you about it? When looking at this code, i am asking myself why you did not split the logic of your Route into a ProjectRoute and a subordinated TaskRoute. Wouldn't that work for you?

**Update: Response to your changes**

Nesting resources is likely the key to success in your case:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('project', { path: '/project/:project_id' }, function(){
    this.resource('task', { path: '/task/:task_id' });
  });
});
```

Since the TaskRoute is nested not you have to rename it to ProjectTaskRoute:

```
App.ProjectTaskRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
...
});
```

This should enable you to remove the `parentProjectId property` from the Route.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that the model method is only called on first load, but it explains a lot of quirkiness I've been seeing. For example, my code above doesn't work if I open /project/1/tasks/2 directly, because `model` isn't called, so the `parentProjectId` attribute isn't set. In that case, I have to do `var parentProject = this.modelFor('project')` inside `setupController`.

I do have a separate ProjectRoute. Opening /project/1 will show tasks for a project. Clicking a task will open /project/1/tasks/1. The task view needs a link back to the project, so I'm pulling the project from the URL.

Comment: So it works now? My idea was also to use this.modelFor("project"). When you enter your app via /project/1/tasks/2, the ProjectRoute should be hit first and its model hook. Afterwards you can use modelFor to access it. It feels only a little bit redundant to set the parentProject in your controller, when you use ember-data to model your data. Shouldn't exist that property on your TaskModel?

Comment: A task can belong to multiple projects (think of projects like tags), so instead of having a "belongs to project" association it's a "has many projects" association. Thus, I can't tell which project I'm inside of (and thus where the back button should link to) just by looking at the task. I have to check the URL. Anyway, I'll try the modelFor thing. I think I have my routes set up incorrectly, so going to /project/1/task/2 is hitting TaskRoute first. I think I need to nest my task routes inside my project routes? I'll update my question to show what my routes look like.

Comment: Yes, your routes should definitely be nested! Then the ProjectRoute would be hit first. I will comment on your update, when i have time.

Answer (score 2):

Since Ember 1.8, the Route class has a [paramsFor](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.1/classes/Route/methods/paramsFor?anchor=paramsFor) function:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
    setupController(controller) {
        this._super(...arguments);
        const params = this.paramsFor('name.of.your.route')
    }
});
```